# Disable click events from queuing on a widget while another function runs

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a function (A) that is bound to a click event on a Canvas. At some point, function A calls another function (B). The canvas contents may change in function B, so I want it to ignore canvas click events while it's running. I've tried setting a bool variable that is checked when function A is called to False before the function B is called and then resetting it to True when the function B is done, but the event still queues with bad mouse coordinates for the new contents. I've tried re-binding canvas click events to a function (C) that just returns "break" then calling the function B then re-binding canvas click events back to function A. Still queues with bad mouse coordinates for the new contents. I've tried setting the canvas state to "disabled" calling function B then setting the state to "normal". I've tried returning "break" from function A, function B, and from both. I get the same result it still queues with bad mouse coordinates for the new contents. Any suggestions?

the code I'm using for testing options in its current state:

```
import time
from tkinter import *

class test_form(object):
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self._CreateGUI()

    def _CreateGUI(self):
        geom = "200x175+0+0"
        self.master.geometry(geom)
        self.xx=Canvas(bg='#ff0000',width=100,height=75)
        self.xx.bind('<ButtonRelease>',self.test_button)
        self.xx.pack()

    def waste_time(self):
        print('time wasted')
        time.sleep(10)
        return "break"

    def test_button(self,event=None):
        self.waste_time()
        return "break"

def start_gui():
    root = Tk()
    form_load = test_form(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start_gui()
```

Comment: Please try to provide a [mcve] that illustrates the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following approach seems to fix your problem.  It's likely similar to one you've already tried but with an `after()` thrown in:

```
class test_form(object):
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self._CreateGUI()

    def _CreateGUI(self):
        geom = "200x175+0+0"
        self.master.geometry(geom)
        self.xx = Canvas(bg='#ff0000', width=100, height=75)
        self.xx.pack()

        self.notice()

    def waste_time(self):
        print('time wasted')
        time.sleep(10)

    def notice(self):
        self.xx.bind('<ButtonRelease>', self.test_button)

    def ignore(self):
        self.xx.bind('<ButtonRelease>', lambda event: "break")

    def test_button(self, event):
        self.ignore()
        self.waste_time()
        self.master.after(500, self.notice)
```

Comment: I tried something with after that didn't work but this does, so clearly what I tried was somehow different. Thanks.